# 2012 KTM Duke 200 - Low acceleration in low rpm

Tags: motorcycle, rpm, performance, ktm, duke

Recently my bike (KTM Duke 200) is suffocating to deliver enough power between 2000-3000 RPM. I took the bike to a service station and they told me that its an engine problem, low compression and needs immediate repair.

What could be the real issue?

will be just a fuel filter problem?

Why it always happen at 2000-3000 RPM?

Edit: After half an hour from engine start or running 6 KM, this issue gets reduced considerably.

RPM's hang at higher then idle then fall.

The airbox is broken.

Comment: You are saying you get it above 3k rpm and it runs like a scalded ape?

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 is asking an important question. How is the acceleration below 2000 rpm and above 3000 rpm? Is it as it should be?

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Once it crosses 3K RPM, it goes skaaadooossshhhh!!!

Comment: Bike model is 2012,  KTM Duke 200

Comment: What makes you think the service station's diagnosis is wrong? Those symptoms sound consistent with low compression to me

Comment: @DucatiKiller Yeah, it hangs before the RPM falls

Comment: @DucatiKiller Broken airbox and this, well..how the RPM fall is so consistent and how does it gets stable after the engine gets heated up a little.

Comment: Thats it, I covered everything as a rider. Just a rider. (Please don't say that a rider need to feel the pulse of the engine)

Comment: Is it on choke when the RPM's hang then fall?  After the choke is OFF does this behavior of hanging RPM's still exist?

Comment: can you add your airbox issue into this question.  They seem directly related.